# Putting name to aggregated funtion in groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to add a name to the sum column and call it 'my_sum' [like the "as" in SQL  sum(age) as my_sum]

I managed to do this

```
my_group=df.groupby(['year']).agg({ 'age':{'my_sum': 'sum'}})
```

Do you think there is an easier way starting from this?:

```
my_group=df.groupby(['year'])['age'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `name`:

```
my_group=df.groupby(['year'])['age'].sum().reset_index(name='my_sum')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2000,2001,2000],
                   'age':[40,50,60]})
print (df)
   age  year
0   40  2000
1   50  2001
2   60  2000

my_group=df.groupby(['year'])['age'].sum().reset_index(name='my_sum')
print (my_group)
   year  my_sum
0  2000     100
1  2001      50
```